# if then using spinner displayed value

Tags: java, android

I get FC when running but it compiles.

NOTE: Changes have been made following Rasel's comment's.  Still FC's

```
                        btnExecute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() //this worked
        {
            private AlertDialog show;
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            { //start of get stack shape and provide area and equivalent diameter
              //20110720
              //just trying to evaluate the shape to use the correct inputs for area calculation
              //I will then add and evaluate for the units of input to build universal
              //values(_eng and _met)variables to use for all further calculations. KISS!

                if (((m1_ss_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Square")))) //cant compare a string with == operator.  Use equals() to compare
                {
                    if ((m1_sqs1.getText().length() == 0)              //if m1_sqs1 is empty
                        || (m1_sqs1.getText().toString().equals("")))  //if m1_sqs1 is blank
                    {           
                            show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error") //this worked
                                .setMessage("The Square Side length is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();          
                    } else
                        {
                            double result = new Double(m1_sqs1.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_sqs1.getText().toString());   
                            m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                        } //end of square area
                } else      

                    if (((m1_ss_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Rectangle"))))
                    {
                        if ((m1_rs1.getText().length() == 0)
                            || (m1_rs1.getText().toString().equals("")
                            || (m1_rs2.getText().length() == 0)
                            || (m1_rs2.getText().toString().equals(""))))
                        {
                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("A Rectangle Side length is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
                        } else 
                            {
                                double result = new Double(m1_rs1.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_rs2.getText().toString());   
                                m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                            } //end of rectangle area
                } else

                    if (((m1_ss_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Circle"))))
                    {
                        if ((m1_cd.getText().length() == 0)            
                            || (m1_cd.getText().toString().equals("")))
                        {
                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("The Circle Diameter is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
                        } else 
                            {
                                double result = new Double(m1_cd.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_cd.getText().toString());   
                                m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                            } //end of circle area
                } else

                        if (((m1_ss_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Elliptical")))) 
                        {
                            if ((m1_els1.getText().length() == 0)           
                            || (m1_els1.getText().toString().equals("")
                            || (m1_els2.getText().length() == 0)
                            || (m1_els2.getText().toString().equals(""))))
                            {
                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("An Elliptical Diameter is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
                        } else 
                            {
                                double result = new Double(m1_els1.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_els2.getText().toString());   
                                m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                            }; //end of elliptical area
                    } // end of onClick code
                }
        });
```

Comment: can you format your question properly, its difficult to read ...

Comment: can you put your logcat error

Comment: Displayed com.androidbook.triviaquiz8/.QuizHelpActivity: +656ms
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
Sending signal. PID: 22123 SIG: 9

Comment: See after commenting the Dialog

Comment: i have no idea what that means.

Comment: do you mean // in front of 3 dialog alert lines?

Comment: yes,Your problem may be in the AlertDialog or in the double formatting

Comment: GOT IT WORKING.  I was missing m1_ss_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.m1_ss_spinner);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling seems to only verify code but not logic  One needs to be very careful with code and I now recommend plenty of comments and strict format with indentions so if statements are easy to determine the beginning and end  FCs occur when the program is left with decision it cant make

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a string with == operator.Use equals() method to compare.Try like this

```
 if (((m1_ss_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Square")))) //need to prove this

                    {

                        if ((m1_sqs1.getText().length() == 0)           //if m1_sqs1 is empty
                            || (m1_sqs1.getText().toString().equals("")))   //if m1_sqs1 is blank
```

Comment: Man I thank-you.  I would be a good student, need to find a class!

Comment: made the changes, I understand the new logic but the thing continues to FC so I am off to learn about debugging.  The java stuff seems all correct now and I had the square piece working last night but wasn't yet evaluating the shape spinner.  I knew I would get tp this hurdle eventually, learning debug.  this whole processed is has been the normal adventure for learning, I am getting ready to soon start asking really good questions :)

Comment: comment section too small and formatting is crazy.  do i start a new thread?